# Divide different node_exporter memory types by the total memory using group_left

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I would like to create a graph of the proportion of total memory consumed by each of the following for a given `instance`:

- `node_memory_MemFree_bytes{instance="$instance"}`
- `node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance="$instance"}`
- `node_memory_Buffers_bytes{instance="$instance"}`
- `node_memory_Cached_bytes{instance="$instance"}`

I know I can create a single graph from 4 separate queries where each metric is divided by `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="$instance"}`:

- Query A: `node_memory_MemFree_bytes{instance="$instance"} / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="$instance"}`
- Query B: `node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance="$instance"} / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="$instance"}`
- Query C: `node_memory_Buffers_bytes{instance="$instance"} / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="$instance"}`
- Query D: `node_memory_Cached_bytes{instance="$instance"} / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="$instance"}`

I feel like there should be a terser way of doing this with `group_left` since the right hand side is the same for each query and the left hand side can be reduced to a single query:

- Left: `{__name__=~"node_memory_(MemFree|MemAvailable|Buffers|Cached)_bytes",instance="$instance"}`
- Right: `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="$instance"}`

If I understand [the "Operators" docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/) and [this blog post](https://www.robustperception.io/using-group_left-to-calculate-label-proportions) correctly, I should be able to use `group_left` to do this in a single query. However, I've been unable to do so.

I reason that since the left and right side of the equation have exactly the same labels excluding `__name__`, I shouldn't need to use `ignoring` or `on` for the `group_left` operator:

```
{__name__=~"node_memory_(MemFree|MemAvailable|Buffers|Cached)_bytes",instance="$instance"}
/
on() group_left node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="$instance"}
```

This query gives me an error:

```
"multiple matches for labels: grouping labels must ensure unique matches"
```

The same is true if I use `ignoring()` or any other combination of `on(<labels>)` and `ignoring(<labels>)`. I can't wrap my head around what I'm missing here, is it a problem that the left and right don't have the same `__name__`? Am I approaching this problem incorrectly?

This operation is incredibly simple in Graphite using the [`divideSeries(dividendSeriesList, divisorSeries)` function](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.divideSeries), surely I can do the same with PromQL.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PromQL strips metric names before matching time series on the left and right side of binary operator such as `/` - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching). In your case time series on the left side differ only by metric names, so PromQL sees  series with identical sets of labels on the left side. The solution is to copy metric names for left-hand side time series into another label before applying the `/` operator and then ignoring this label during the `/` operation. This  can be done with [label_join](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_join) or [label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) functions:

```
label_join({__name__=~"node_memory_(MemFree|MemAvailable|Buffers|Cached)_bytes",instance="$instance"}, "metric_name", "", "__name__")
/
ignoring(metric_name) group_left() node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="$instance"}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the explanation. For anyone who finds this question subsequently and is looking for more on `label_join`: [label_join in the Prometheus docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_join).